# Adding namespace to s3 module

Tags: 7

I have a drupal 7 codebase which I downloaded from a production server and set up locally (using PHP version 7). There is this `amazons3.module` file in which I have to add an extra `namespace Drupal\amazons3` to get it running. If I remove the line, the code throws an error stating : `Error: Class 'Drupal\amazons3\StreamWrapperConfiguration' not found in amazons3_upload_location() (line 345 of /xxx/yyy/sites/all/modules/amazons3/amazons3.module).`.

Why am I having to add this code when it is not there in the production version and nor in the github [codebase](https://github.com/justafish/drupal_amazons3/blob/7.x-2.x/amazons3.module) ?

Comment: Hello! Did you check if the requirements are complete for the module? https://www.drupal.org/project/amazons3   It seems to require Composer Manager and that might handle the requirement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this by linking to the correct path where the composer was placed (as suggested by Japo).

EDIT:

In another server setup, the same issue was fixed by adding php-curl module.